# vba JSON call not returning same value

Tags: json, excel, vba, get, request

I'm trying to get a response from API call via vba. But I'm not getting the same string. I'm new to API's and I'm not sure where it is going wrong. Here is how I get the HTML response:

```
    myurl = Constants.BACKLOG_SITE & "/api/v2/issues?apiKey=" & APIkey
    xmlhttp.Open "GET", myurl, False
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/json"
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
    xmlhttp.send
    rURL = xmlhttp.responseText
```

This is returning:

```
[
   {
      "id":4883687,
      "projectId":80977,
      "issueKey":"EXCEL_TOOL_DEV-7",
      "keyId":7,
      "issueType":{
         "id":374448,
         "projectId":80977,
         "name":"タスク",
         "color":"#7ea800",
         "displayOrder":0
      },
      "summary":"TASK4",
      "description":"TASK4",
      "resolution":null,
      "priority":{
         "id":3,
         "name":"中"
      },
      "status":{
         "id":1,
         "name":"未対応"
      },
      "assignee":{
         "id":95981,
         "userId":null,
         "name":"辻本",
         "roleType":1,
         "lang":null,
         "mailAddress":null,
         "nulabAccount":null
      },
      "category":[

      ],
      "versions":[

      ],
      "milestone":[

      ],
      "startDate":"2018-02-28T00:00:00Z",
      "dueDate":"2018-04-15T00:00:00Z",
      "estimatedHours":null,
      "actualHours":null,
      "parentIssueId":null,
      "createdUser":{
         "id":183845,
         "userId":"brethren-i",
         "name":"Brethren",
         "roleType":2,
         "lang":"en",
         "mailAddress":"brethren-i@t-axis.co.jp",
         "nulabAccount":null
      },
      "created":"2018-03-02T06:48:13Z",
      "updatedUser":{
         "id":183845,
         "userId":"brethren-i",
         "name":"Brethren",
         "roleType":2,
         "lang":"en",
         "mailAddress":"brethren-i@t-axis.co.jp",
         "nulabAccount":null
      },
      "updated":"2018-03-02T06:48:13Z",
      "customFields":[

      ],
      "attachments":[

      ],
      "sharedFiles":[

      ],
      "stars":[

      ]
   }
]
```

But when I access the request site, it is returning two values. Which should be the right one. What am I missing?

```
[
   {
      "id":4883687,
      "projectId":80977,
      "issueKey":"EXCEL_TOOL_DEV-7",
      "keyId":7,
      "issueType":{
         "id":374448,
         "projectId":80977,
         "name":"タスク",
         "color":"#7ea800",
         "displayOrder":0
      },
      "summary":"TASK4",
      "description":"TASK4",
      "resolution":null,
      "priority":{
         "id":3,
         "name":"中"
      },
      "status":{
         "id":1,
         "name":"未対応"
      },
      "assignee":{
         "id":95981,
         "userId":null,
         "name":"辻本",
         "roleType":1,
         "lang":null,
         "mailAddress":null,
         "nulabAccount":null
      },
      "category":[

      ],
      "versions":[

      ],
      "milestone":[

      ],
      "startDate":"2018-02-28T00:00:00Z",
      "dueDate":"2018-04-15T00:00:00Z",
      "estimatedHours":null,
      "actualHours":null,
      "parentIssueId":null,
      "createdUser":{
         "id":183845,
         "userId":"brethren-i",
         "name":"Brethren",
         "roleType":2,
         "lang":"en",
         "mailAddress":"brethren-i@t-axis.co.jp",
         "nulabAccount":null
      },
      "created":"2018-03-02T06:48:13Z",
      "updatedUser":{
         "id":183845,
         "userId":"brethren-i",
         "name":"Brethren",
         "roleType":2,
         "lang":"en",
         "mailAddress":"brethren-i@t-axis.co.jp",
         "nulabAccount":null
      },
      "updated":"2018-03-02T06:48:13Z",
      "customFields":[

      ],
      "attachments":[

      ],
      "sharedFiles":[

      ],
      "stars":[

      ]
   },
   {
      "id":4883450,
      "projectId":80977,
      "issueKey":"EXCEL_TOOL_DEV-6",
      "keyId":6,
      "issueType":{
         "id":374448,
         "projectId":80977,
         "name":"タスク",
         "color":"#7ea800",
         "displayOrder":0
      },
      "summary":"TASK3",
      "description":"TASK3",
      "resolution":null,
      "priority":{
         "id":2,
         "name":"高"
      },
      "status":{
         "id":1,
         "name":"未対応"
      },
      "assignee":{
         "id":95981,
         "userId":null,
         "name":"辻本",
         "roleType":1,
         "lang":null,
         "mailAddress":null,
         "nulabAccount":null
      },
      "category":[

      ],
      "versions":[

      ],
      "milestone":[

      ],
      "startDate":"2018-02-28T00:00:00Z",
      "dueDate":"2018-04-15T00:00:00Z",
      "estimatedHours":null,
      "actualHours":null,
      "parentIssueId":null,
      "createdUser":{
         "id":183845,
         "userId":"brethren-i",
         "name":"Brethren",
         "roleType":2,
         "lang":"en",
         "mailAddress":"brethren-i@t-axis.co.jp",
         "nulabAccount":null
      },
      "created":"2018-03-02T06:35:35Z",
      "updatedUser":{
         "id":183845,
         "userId":"brethren-i",
         "name":"Brethren",
         "roleType":2,
         "lang":"en",
         "mailAddress":"brethren-i@t-axis.co.jp",
         "nulabAccount":null
      },
      "updated":"2018-03-02T06:45:28Z",
      "customFields":[

      ],
      "attachments":[

      ],
      "sharedFiles":[

      ],
      "stars":[

      ]
   }
]
```

Comment: Please elaborate how do you get the second snippet? Do you request the site via browser?

Comment: Are you using Debug.Print to view the first response?

Comment: @omegastripes yes second response is from browser

Comment: Then you should find the difference between headers (and maybe parameters) made by VBA XHR and by browser. Try to use Fiddler with filtering by `BACKLOG_SITE`, it's quite powerful and suitable tool. Note, using `xmlhttp` (BTW, where is a declaration and initialization?) you are not able to control cookies and redirections.